# How can I add a dropdown of font names that also uses the font for display, so users can preview the font?

Tags: laravel-backpack

Part of my CMS allows users to specify what font should be used for displaying a field. The font list will never be more than 10 fonts, ever, normally fewer.

I'm wondering if there is a way to display the dropdown list such that the actual font is used for each font name.

If this isn't possible (or would require too much customization), I'd be happy to offer a preview of how the font looks next to the form (so if you can't answer the first question, maybe you can answer the second question).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a custom field in Backpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type) for this purpose, and in that blade file you can use any JS you like. I found https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/system-google-font-picker.html which looks like it's exactly what you want, from [its demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/system-google-font-picker/).

Comment: Brilliant. Indeed, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!